Flutter Facebook Audience Network does not show ads in production
I’m using Facebook Audience Network (FAN) in my Flutter app.
Things are working fine when testing in both user and debug mode on the device.
But when publishing it in the Play Store, the ads are not displayed.
Does anyone have an app published in the Play Store which uses FAN in this moment?
The logs indicate that the error is: No fill.
But my app is approved in the store and with FAN and I also have a payment method configured.
{
  "error_message": "No fill",
  "error_code": 1001,
  "invalidated": true,
  "placement_id": "10198386XXXXXX_10198482262XXXXX"
}

I have published my app in the Play Store, checked the logs for errors, checked if requests are coming to the Audience Manager and everything indicates that it is configured correctly, but the ads still do not appear in my published app.

No fill means there is no ads to show for the ad request you made. Once you have enough impression request it will start showing automatically

@KaushikChandru But it is not showing ads for any users in production

Yes it will start showing once you have enough impression requests from the app and if FAN has ads in your demographic location

@KaushikChandru I made a native app using kotlin with the same domain as the app that is in production and deployed the ads to it using the same positionIds as the Flutter one, and instead if the actual ads appear all at once, which leads me to wondering if this is some blocking by Facebook for Flutter apps.

@KaushikChandru You have any app published in the Play Store monetized with FAN?

I had one but not in store now
